# How old are the major characters on The Dragon Prince?

Tags: the-dragon-prince

The ages of most of the characters on *The Dragon Prince* are not mentioned often, but I recall some bits of information here and there. For instance, Ezran says the events of the first season happened when he was nine (so he may now be around eleven). On the older side, Aaravos has apparently been around for at least 1000 years or so. However, some characters' ages are perhaps less clear.

How old are the major characters in *The Dragon Prince* as of the fourth season, particularly those who are still young (Claudia, most of the heroes) or inhumanly old (the Dragon Queen, Aaravos)?